# what does dataloaders in pytorch give in each iteration when we use map style?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = 3, shuffle = True)
```

```
for batch in train_loader:
      model.train()
      x,y=batch
      pred=model(x)
```

I have used map iteration in dataloaders
as of my concern , for each iteration i receive a ind,data from dataloader
why are we predicting the x (ind) in my code

Answer (score 0):

The dataloader creates a stack of your torch tensor dataset, but this typically depends on your dataset. How much it stacks depends on your batch size, in your example which is 3.